# Callback works multithread but not multiprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, callback, multiprocessing

I have a tinker IMU and I'm using their library which is utilizing a callback to output data. I have implemented a multithread approach which works fine but now I want to make it multiprocess instead for better concurrency.  The multiprocess starts the startIMUData function fine but it won't call the myIMUCallback.

```
def myIMUCallback():
    print("callback called!")

# Function to start recording IMU dimport serialata via callback function above
def startIMUData(q):
    print("Starting IMU!")

    HOST = "localhost"
    PORT = 4223
    UID = "6Dcx3Y" # Change XXYYZZ to the UID of your IMU Brick 2.0

    ipcon = IPConnection() # Create IP connection
    imu = BrickIMUV2(UID, ipcon) # Create device object

    ipcon.connect(HOST, PORT) 

    # myIMUCallback is NOT being called in process version
    imu.register_callback(imu.CALLBACK_ALL_DATA, myIMUCallback)

    imu.set_all_data_period(100)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    q = Queue()   
    # This works
    threadIMU = Thread(target = startIMUData, args = (q, ))
    threadIMU.start()
    threadIMU.join()

    #This doesn't work, calls startIMUData fine but ignores myIMUCallback
    processIMU = multiprocessing.Process(target=startIMUData, args=(q, ))
    processIMU.start()
    processIMU.join()
```

Comment: Have you checked that it isn't just the `print()` that is not working? Printing in multiple processes is not trivial.

Comment: @KlausD. I had multiple lines of code in myIMUCallback including creating file etc nothing was being called.  I just deleted most to make it easier to read.

Comment: The [mu-v2-brick-python-examples](https://www.tinkerforge.com/en/doc/Software/Bricks/IMUV2_Brick_Python.html#imu-v2-brick-python-examples) have those lines at the End. `raw_input("Press key to exit\n") # Use input() in Python 3
    ipcon.disconnect()` Add it to see if it makes any different.